# What is it called when f(g(x)) = x?

Tags: terminology

There are a couple of function pairs which give the identity when composed, e.g.,

- `decrypt(encrypt(value)) == value`
- `deserialize(serialize(data, filepath)) == data`

What is this property called? Suppose one function undoes the property of the other, and it is guaranteed that this is possible for all values (within the domain of interest).

Comment: This is called invertible

Comment: Add also call it f(f<sup>-1</sup>(x)).

Comment: As you mention [elsewhere](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128879/how-is-it-called-when-fgx-x#comment270396_128887), depending on which function you focus on, one describes `d(e(x)) = x` by saying that `d` is right invertible (with right inverse `e`) and `e` is left invertible (with left inverse `d`); invertibility is only when the conversion works both ways.  Notice that your `deserialize` and `serialize` pair is more subtle; here we have, schematically, not `d(s(x)) = x` but `d(s(x, y)) = x`.

Comment: Well, for that, we could just fix the file path and call `s(x) = serialize(x, path)`.

Comment: The generalization is the difference between an injective function (a function with a left inverse), a surjective function (a function with a right inverse), and a bijective function (a function with both a left and a right inverse, which are provably the same).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would add to the existing answer that the composition $h = f \circ g$ is the identity, which you already pointed out. This means that $g$ is the right-inverse of $f$, and $f$ is the left-inverse of $g$. That makes each of $f$ and $g$ *invertible* on the given side. For the pairs you have given, I would expect $g \circ f$ to also be the identity in the naïve/straightforward case, and so the left/rightness is flipped, and you have full inversion. The domain matters, as usual.

As pointed out in the comments, this is not necessarily the case for some kinds of the functions you give—re-encrypting after retrieving the original value $(g \circ f \circ g)(x)$ may not necessarily give the same encrypted code $g(x)$; but then, it’s not nearly useful to consider $g$ a function, for the normal rules don’t apply. Notice that we still take the value passed to $f$ (here, the decryptor) to be an encrypted value; we assume the domain of $f$ to be properly encrypted values. Mathematically we are unable to apply $f$ to anything else (though I could have used a name like $y = g(x)$). Programmatically, of course, the type system *may* permit values outside the domain to be given, and then we either get an error or garbage. Again, I consider those irrelevant and outside the domain here.

Versioned serialization actually doesn’t have this issue—a function that deserializes or serializes a different version than $f$ or $g$ is *not* $f$ or $g$, respectively, and therefore not relevant! **The domain matters.**

We also have $\forall x$ in the domain $h(x) = x$ by definition, and that means every $x$ is a fix-point of $h$ (this is trivially true for any identity).

Comment: Is there a name for this pair of (function, (right)-inverse of that function)? I want to write something about "intertible" functions ... but especially invertible functions where you actually have the inverse functions.

Comment: @MartinThoma to be honest I wouldn’t know

Comment: Thank you :-) I guess this doesn't have a specific name and I'll simply go for "a function and it's right-inverse function" :-)

Comment: @MartinThoma, one often refers to functors $(F, G)$ where $G$ is a right adjoint to $F$ as an adjoint pair.  I can imagine that people would understand that you meant if you referred to $(f, g)$ where $g$ is right inverse to $f$ as an inverse pair.  (But, as with all non-universal terminology, you should define it the first time you use it.)

Comment: Also, although I'm not familiar enough with these areas to know myself, in computability theory, the statement that a computable function is (right) invertible is weaker than the statement that it has a computable (right) inverse; so you might look there, or perhaps in constructive logic, where also one is concerned not just with existence but with a witness, for terminology.

Comment: @LSpice I thought category theory was big on *universality*, though. ;)

Comment: I wouldn't expect the given examples to be (fully) invertible at all, at least if the domain consits of all byte-strings. Deserializing "foobla" into an integer will probably either be undefined or return some kind of error object - in any case not something that serializes back into "foobla". Similarly, most encryption tends to have padding that is discarded - except maybe stream ciphers, which are a very special case ($f=g$) anyway.

Comment: This answer reads as if left-, right-invertibility, and full invertbiiity are confused with each other. I don't think the parenthesized attributions particularly help in understanding the answer. I'd recommend spelling them out. Importantly, **the pairs OP has given are usually *not* inverses of each other**: encryption is non-deterministic most of the time, hence `enc(dec(x)) == x` is *not* the norm, but a special case. Also, serialization often deals with migrations between format versions. Hence, `ser(deser(x))` might upgrade to a newer format than is used in `x`.

Comment: @ComFreek ive tried to address both parts of your comment. Let me know if you feel there is still room for improvement.

Comment: If $f \circ g$ is the identity, then $g \circ f \circ g$ is just $g$ again; this cannot fail, at least, as you say, if $g$ is a function.  The mathematical subtlety that arises is whether $g \circ f$ is the identity:  that is, whether, in this language, encrypting an output `f(x)` of the decryption function produces the input `x` to the decryption function, *even if* that input `x` was not originally known to be an encrypted output `g(y)`.

Comment: @LSpice and then again you have the question of domain: is $x : \forall y : x \neq g(y)$ in the domain of $f$ or not? I would argue no, but it depends on definitions I suppose. If you don't know what set(s) $x$ is in, how can you possibly know if it is in the domain of $f$?

Answer (score 11):

The language borrowed from category theory is that `f` is a *retraction* of `g`, and `g` is a *section* of `f`.

If `f` is both a retraction and a section of `g`, then it's called an *inversion*.

Comment: Is there a name for this pair of (function, (right)-inverse of that function)? I want to write something about "intertible" functions ... but especially invertible functions where you actually have the inverse functions.

Comment: Yes, exactly what Ashley said. If $r \circ s = 1$, then $r$ is the retraction of $s$ and $s$ is the section of $r$.

Answer (score 1):

decrypt is the **inverse** of encrypt

deserialize is the **inverse** of serialize

In other words, the composition of a function and its inverse are the identity function.

Comment: Is there a name for this pair of (function, (right)-inverse of that function)? I want to write something about "intertible" functions ... but especially invertible functions where you actually have the inverse functions.

Comment: The pair of functions would simply be called "a function and its inverse".  There is no right- or left-inverse, it is simply an inverse.  It works in both directions.  Encrypt is the inverse of decrypt, and decrypt is the inverse of encrypt.  Encrypt is the double-inverse of encrypt, because two inverses cancel each other out.

Comment: It is not true that there is no such thing as a right or left inverse; there can be either, and it is only when they coincide that one speaks of an inverse without qualification.  For example, a lossy encoding might have a right inverse (you might be able to produce un-encoded 'text' with a given encoding), but, by the definition of 'lossy', does not have a left inverse (you cannot recover the original 'text' from its lossy encoding).

Comment: Both pairs are usually *not* inverses of each other, see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128879/how-is-it-called-when-fgx-x#comment270465_128887.

Answer (score -1):

If for all $x$ in some set $S$, we have $f(g(x)) = x$ then $f$ is the "***inverse***" of $g$

Comment: Is there a name for this pair of (function, (right)-inverse of that function)? I want to write something about "intertible" functions ... but especially invertible functions where you actually have the inverse functions.

Comment: In your situation, $f$ is a (not necessarily the) *left* inverse of $g$.